# neo4j concurrency issue - deleting and matching

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have one program that builds graphs. I have a reaper which deletes old graphs.

Sometimes, the set of nodes returned by the queries used when building the graphs overlaps with the set of nodes being reaped. This is giving me a spurious `"EntityNotFound: Node with id xxxxxx"` error.

I say it is spurious because the reality is that we're not deleting the nodes we're adding - they are on separate graphs.

However, the loader's MATCH has two parts:

```
MATCH(n: MYNODE {indexed-var:"ddd", version:"xxx"} ...
```

It is true that some `n` indexed by "ddd" can be in the graph being deleted, but the specific version of node `n` I am adding will always have a 'safe' version number. However, `EXPLAIN` clearly shows I am sucking in multiple MYNODE nodes, and then filtering to the specific node. I am guessing that the delete program is deleting a MYNODE node after the loader has fetched it, but before it is filtered.

The loader and deleter are both running with transactions, so it isn't an immediate thing - the failure happens on commit.

Can I use `_LOCK_` to prevent the read and the delete from acting on the same nodes at the same time?  Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to:

1. Add to `MYNODE` another property (let's call it `id`) whose value is a string that concatenates index and version, separated by a delimiter character (let's say it is "|").
2. Create an index on `:MYNODE(id)`.
3. Change your `MATCH` clause to:

   ```
   MATCH(n: MYNODE {id:"ddd|xxx"} ...
   ```

The use of an index allows Cypher to immediately get the desired node(s), avoiding the need to iterate through all the `MYNODE` nodes and filtering out the undesired ones (some of which may no longer exist). This approach has the added benefit of being much faster.